# VBA DoCmd.Open form on a group of records

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a form (frmQATeam) that summarizes records based on a query. (qQATeam) It only shows some of the smaller fields so I want to have a button that takes me to a full screen view of the complete record(frmQASingleView) including the memo fields and other larger format items. I want to see every record that appears on the summary form, not just one. On this button I am using VBA to pull the full view form up. I have tried a:

WHERE method: `DoCmd.OpenForm "frmQASingleView", , ,"Id = " Me.ID` but that provides only the selected record, and not all 6 that are showing in frmQAteam.

FilterName Method: `DoCmd.OpenForm "QASingleView", , "qQATeamViewAll"` but this method returns all records in the table.

And a method I saw suggested elsewhere on the net (yes its in navigation subforms)

`Dim rs As Object
Dim lngBookmark As Long
lngBookmark = Me.ID
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmQASingleView"
Set rs = Forms!MainMenu.Form!btnManagersMenu.Form!NavigationSubform.Form.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "ID = " & lngBookmark`

But this method also returns all records in the Table.

My final attempt was to set up a macro even though people have warned me against them to use the OpenForm setting and set the filter based on the query. In this case I discovered that you cannot use a macro to filter a query that is based on two or more tables with a relationship.

I'm at my wits end and I'm hoping someone can help.

Comment: I have lots of forms and queries and I dont want to have a  frmQASingleView for every type of query I want to see. Maybe I should see if there is a way in VBA to set the forms recordsource property as I open the form?

Comment: So then maybe you want to do `Forms!frmQASingleView.RecordSource = "something"`, is that right?

Comment: That worked! I changed the code to DoCmd.OpenForm "frmQASingleView" Forms!frmQASingleView.RecordSource = "qQATeam" and that worked very well. If you move that into an answer I'll give you the credit, and thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the `RecordSource` for `frmQASingleView` at runtime.  So if you change it to use the same query, `qQATeam`, as the first form, it has to display the same 6 rows.  :-)

Suggest you first open the form empty and hidden.

```vba
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="frmQASingleView", View:=acNormal, WhereCondition:="1=2", WindowMode:=acHidden
```

Then change its `RecordSource` and unhide it.

```vba
Forms!frmQASingleView.RecordSource = "qQATeam"
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="frmQASingleView" View:=acNormal, WindowMode:=acWindowNormal
```